Dealing with denorms in the ARM Cortex M4 FPU
Okay, a year ago I asked this other question and got zero responses.
Now, I will try to get a little more specific:  The ARM chip that is in this product is the STM32F407 and I got the docs on that particular chip.  It appears to have a Cortex M4 core and an FPU.
In the Cortex A9 docs I can find a reference to 4 bits in some control register called FtZ that I believe might correspond to the Intel FTZ and DAZ flags.  But for the M4, I cannot even tell that these flags exist, even though there is an FPU.
I wanna do some real-time floating-point DSP with this ARM chip and I don't want any exceptions to happen if we stumble upon a denormalized floating-point number (either read from memory which is what DAZ is for, or that gets computed which is what FTZ is for).  Has anyone worked with the M4 FPU and come upon this denorm issue?  I just wish that all FPUs would deal with denorms normally as if they were just as legitimate as normalized floats.  But if I can't have that, I sure as hell do not want the thing to choke on me if it comes across a denorm.
Does anyone have some experience with this issue that they might share their wisdom?

The A9 is a chip designed to support a beefy OS, and the M4 is a microcontroller. It's certainly not surprising that there's less functionality.

FWIW, I can't find any reference to those flags in the index of Yiu, The Definitive Guide to ARM Cortex-M3 and Cortex- M4 processors, 3rd edition, nor any entry starting with "denorm"

Oops -- I lied!!  They do mention denorms in the double precision floating point section 13.1.4,

The book is https://shop.elsevier.com/books/the-definitive-guide-to-arm-cortex-m3-and-cortex-m4-processors/yiu/978-0-12-408082-9

Have you read the ARM reference manual for the cortex M4 processor? https://documentation-service.arm.com/static/5f19da2a20b7cf4bc524d99a?token=  on page 2-2 there is the statement "Hardware support for denormals and all IEEE rounding modes." I have no clue what denormals are but you might find valuable information there.

I've only looked at the documentation available here.  Specifically the PM0214 Programming manual STM32 Cortex®-M4 MCUs and MPUs programming manual.  I will now look at the link you cite.

@Mau5 I was about to post a reference to that from the NXP boards at https://community.nxp.com/t5/LPC-Microcontrollers/Floating-point-denormalized-numbers-support-on-NXP-M4f/m-p/592307 -- but it's not real clear to me what "hardware support" actually means -- does it do the calc, or does it Flush to zero.

If it does the calc with no extra instruction cycles, that would be beautiful.  That's sorta about the question I asked last year.  But if it Flushes-to-Zero (upon computation and output) and reads Denormals-are-Zero, without any hiccup, that would be okay.  I just don't want an [] exception in my real-time processing!! [Moderator removed profanity]

It looks like that document (which I didn't have) has the answers.  In section 7-2-2 .  On page 7-4.  And they do Flush-to-Zero or cause an exception.  The latter is bad.

@ScottSeidman as said, my knowledge about floating-point numbers is very limited and I will not be able to answer this question. But I do know that the ARM reference manuals are the go-to for every processor-related question. The ST reference manuals typically focus on the processor's peripherals (since they most likely develop them on their own) but not on the CPU or FPU (which they buy from ARM).

@Mau5 I think you pointed me to the answers.  Dunno what the goddamn chip does if if a denorm goes into a floating-point calculation.  I presume if the FZ bit is set, it also flushes that to zero and no hiccup.

@robertbristow-johnson - Hi, The profanity in the question and in some comments from you, was unacceptable and has been removed. Please don't repeat in future. See here for guidance. Thanks for your cooperation.

From https://shop.elsevier.com/books/the-definitive-guide-to-arm-cortex-m3-and-cortex-m4-processors/yiu/978-0-12-408082-9, if the exponent value is zero and the fraction part of a double is not 0, it's a denormalized value, so yes, the M4 is certainly aware of denorms in double precision.
The FPU on the M4 is single precision, not double, so I wouldn't look for much help from the FPU.  Your calculations will use the double precision libraries, and will be slow.
Bit 7 of the Floating point context adress register is the IDC, Input Denormal cumulative exception bit, set to 1 when a floating point exception occurs, cleared by writing 0 to the bit.
I highly recommend that book.

One thing to watch out for, though, is that STM sometimes doesn't provide full functionality in their instantiations.  For example, the STM Arm Cortexes (cortices??) doesn't let you switch between big endian and little endian representations.

Scott, thank you.  You're +1 because of the time you've taken to answer. I am thoroughly knowledgeable about the IEEE-754 standard. But not of every chip and how they deal with it. I don't want double-precision (it would be slow with an FPU that knows only single-precision). And even single-precision has denorms, but many chips don't do denorms.  They either treat them like zero or they cause an exception.  Because if my year-old question, I don't know there's a single chip out there that does denorms routinely. They cause exceptions or they Flush-To-Zero or Denorms-Are-Zero.

I don't want the former.  Because this is real-time DSP, I don't want an exception to occur just because the data it comes across may occasionally have a denorm. With the Intel chips, people would just set FTZ and DAZ and problem was solved.  I just want to make sure the ARM M4 doesn't [] either freeze or hiccup if my audio DSP encounters a denorm either from computation (like subtracting two nearly identical small numbers and not getting zero) or from reading it from an input.  We're doing only 32-bit float processing.  No doubles. [Moderator removed profanity]

@robertbristow-johnson -- yeah, I know I didn't delve real deep but thought I might be able to get you pointed in the right direction.  I'd offer to run a test case for you, but my toolchain for the STM Cortex hasn't been opened for maybe 6 or 7 years, and I can't commit the time to bring it back up just now.  There should be plenty of people watching the chat who could run an example pretty quickly, if you'd like to go that route.

Once I'm really cooking with this board, I will figure out a test case and see what it does.  And I know, 2 or 3 decades ago, people in the audio DSP community were dealing with this regarding Intel chips.  SHArC chips always treated denorms as zero.  Anyway, if someone else coding low-level floating point with an ARM has also come upon this problem, I would really be interested in what they did about it.

The Cortex-M4 Revision r0p0 Technical Reference Manual section 7.2.2 Modes of operation contains:

The FPU provides three modes of operation to accommodate a variety of applications:

Full-compliance mode on page 7-4
Flush-to-zero mode on page 7-4
Default NaN mode on page 7-4


And Flush-to-zero mode contains:

Setting the FZ bit, FPSCR[24], enables flush-to-zero mode. In this mode, the FPU treats all subnormal input operands of arithmetic CDP operations as zeros in the operation. Exceptions that result from a zero operand are signaled appropriately. VABS, VNEG, and VMOV are not considered arithmetic CDP operations and are not affected by flush-to-zero mode. A result that is tiny, as described in the IEEE 754 standard, for the destination precision is smaller in magnitude than the minimum normal value before rounding and is replaced with a zero. The IDC flag, FPSCR[7], indicates when an input flush occurs. The UFC flag, FPSCR[3], indicates when a result flush occurs.

So, it appears setting the FZ bit will enable flush-to-zero which I think is what the question is asking for.
I also looked at the TI TM4C1231D5PZ datasheet, an an example of a MCU with a ARM Cortex-M4F Processor Core:

Section 3.1.5.2 Modes of Operation contains the same text as the Cortex-M4 Technical Reference Manual.

Register 22: Floating-Point Status Control (FPSC) contains the following:



Bit/Field
Name
Type
Reset
Description




24
FZ
RW
-
Flush-to-Zero ModeWhen set, Flush-to-Zero mode is enabled. When clear, Flush-to-Zero mode is disabled and the behavior of the floating-point system is fully compliant with the IEEE 754 standard.The FZ bit in the FPDSC register holds the default value for this bit.





Admittedly I haven't yet tried setting the FZ bit to confirm its operation.
